# Sticky navbar in css and html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the navbar stick at the top when i scroll down and i found this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp) on w3schools.

But when i add the margin at the top of the main content, the margin seems to get added to the navbar instead since it moves down 100px, can anyone help me out?

This is my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.pages-container p {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.pages-container .last {
  margin-right: 0;
}

nav .title {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<nav>
  <p class="title">Portfolio Willem</p>
  <div class="pages-container">
    <p>Economie</p>
    <p>Bedrijfseconomie</p>
    <p>Wiskunde A</p>
    <p class="last">Geschiedenis</p>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="main">
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

I was expecting the main content to move down and not the navbar.

Comment: Just add `top: 0`  to your nav styles - see the last line of the first paragraph: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed

Comment: Pete, thanks for your reply! this solves the problem of the navbar moving down but does not accomplish the goal to move the main content down, can you help me further?

Edit: Nevermind, it works now! Thank you so much!

Comment: but the main content is moved down - you'll need to explain in more detail what's not working - if you are wanting proper sticky nav so you don't have to put any margin on main, why not use position sticky on your nav instead of fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Add to `<nav>` `top: 0; background: white;`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.pages-container p {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.pages-container .last {
  margin-right: 0;
}

nav .title {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<nav>
  <p class="title">Portfolio Willem</p>
  <div class="pages-container">
    <p>Economie</p>
    <p>Bedrijfseconomie</p>
    <p>Wiskunde A</p>
    <p class="last">Geschiedenis</p>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="main">
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
  <p>test content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I going to answer but you did it, bro.